# Iterate over an object to create options for select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Object I'm trying to iterate over to for the options for a select but I'm getting this error:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<select>` cannot appear as a child
>   of `<select>`.

in my return I have this:

```
                <label>
                Select your trip:
                  <select value={this.state.totalMiles} onChange={this.onTotalMileChange}>
                    <option value="0">Custom Trip</option>
                    {Object.entries(PRESETS).map(([campus, mileage]) => (
                      <select key={campus} value={mileage.map}>{campus.map}</select>))} 
                  </select>
                 </label>
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do i fix this?

here's the object in case that helps:

```
const PRESETS = {
    // round trip for each campus from MWC
    TUL_FULL_TRIP: 341,
    OKC_FULL_TRIP: 156,
    TEXAS_FULL_TRIP: 504,
    alb: 3042,
    bao: 270,
    bnb: 26,
    cen: 33,
    cta: 237,
    edm: 33,
    fts: 379,
    ftw: 435,
    hnv: 1383,
    jnk: 207,
    klr: 391,
    mor: 33,
    msf: 442,
    mus: 44,
    ncs: 1220,
    nkc: 729,
    noc: 35,
    nor: 40,
    okc: 24,
    omh: 954,
    opk: 33,
    ows: 660,
    rga: 437,
    rrn: 1131,
    sba: 229,
    shw: 65,
    soc: 24,
    spf: 570,
    sto: 218,
    stw: 129,
    tul: 218,
    wch: 329,
    wel: 2902,
    wwk: 338,
    ykn: 43,
    ikea: 401

    }
```

Comment: Just like the error says; You're trying to add `<select>` as a child of `<select>`. Use `<option>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be nesting multiple select elements within your parent select element. I believe you meant to use the `<option>` element. From there, you can assign the respective values to the option `value` props.

```
<select value={this.state.totalMiles} onChange={this.onTotalMileChange}>
  <option value="0">Custom Trip</option>
  {
    Object.entries(PRESETS).map(([campus, mileage]) => (
      <option key={campus} value={mileage}>
        {campus}
      </option>
    ))
  } 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks wentjun! Perfect answer!